# How do i list all entries where a specific value in a column does not exist?

Tags: sql

Basically, I have a table called Client Entity that contains an Entity Type column and I have an entity type called BEN.  I want to show all records where this particular type does not exist.  The issue is that the record itself may not exist if the entity type has not been appointed so I am basically asking the query to show me where no 'rows' exists because of this value...

Basically I'm looking for a code to highlight the absence of data, not NULL values.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would make this question much, much clearer for the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table of "records", then you would use `not exists`:

```
select r.*
from records r
where not exists (select 1
                  from cliententity ce
                  where ce.record_id = r.record_id and
                        ce.entity_type = 'BEN'
                 );
```

I don't know what your real table or column names are, but this gives the idea on how to approach the problem.